# Duplicating ScritableObjects with Values per Script Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I am making a Multiplayer Game with MLAPI. The problem is, i have a ability system so every ability get executed over an ScritableObject. The problem is, if i have for example five Players in the scene all Players are referenced to the same ScritableObject. And so when somebody execute a ability. The other players are also doing it.
So my Question is can I duplicate my default ability ScritableObject so that every player has its own abilities ScritableObject but with the same Values as the default ability ScritableObject. I must do that over Script.
I know i could create a new ScritableObject and then make a method who paste my values. But maybe somebody has a better idea??????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can use [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) also for cloning `ScriptableObject` on runtime! Only you can of course not use any component taking more then the original parameter (which makes sense).

And the same way as `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance` this will of course not create an asset but only a runtime instance.

Comment: Ok thx, much thx. That helps me but can i copy a already Existing Scritableobject with the Values. So that i have two existing Scritableobject with the same Values.    Thank you for the Answer

Comment: @Lyksel Well yes ... As said you use `Instantiate` that will create a clone rather than a new empty instance

Comment: Ah now i understand. Sorry . But thx you save me from much error.     THX